# How to add fields to custom module in divi builder plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have created a custom module in divi builder. Below given is the code:

```
function ex_divi_child_theme_setup() {

   if ( class_exists('ET_Builder_Module')) {

      class ET_Builder_Module_Image2 extends ET_Builder_Module {
         function init() {
            $this->name = __( 'Image_1', 'et_builder' );
            $this->slug = 'et_pb_image2';
            // a whole bunch of php code that defines how the class functions
         }
      }
      $et_builder_module_image2 = new ET_Builder_Module_Image2();
      add_shortcode( 'et_pb_image2', array($et_builder_module_image2, '_shortcode_callback') );

   }

}
add_action('et_builder_ready', 'ex_divi_child_theme_setup');
```

I need to add fields to this custom module. How could i achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add your custom field in your custom module, you have to use **"$this->whitelisted_fields"** property and **get_fields()** function. ill give you some example that, how to add text field.

```
class ET_Builder_Module_Image2 extends ET_Builder_Module {
     function init() {
        $this->name = __( 'Image_1', 'et_builder' );
        $this->slug = 'et_pb_image2';
        // a whole bunch of php code that defines how the class functions
     }
$this->whitelisted_fields = array(
        'my_title',
    );
function get_fields () {
    $fields = array(
        'my_title' => array(
            'label' => __( 'My Title', 'wb' ),
            'type' => 'text',
        ),
    );
    return $fields;
}
```

add your custom filed slug in **whitelisted_fields** propertys then add details in **get_fields()** function. i hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I get a notice that whitelisted_fields is deprecated.

Comment: Current version of Divi (3.6) works with advanced_fields instead of whitelisted fields.